# Laravel adds mysql in file path

Tags: laravel, csv, import, path, load

I am facing a weird issue with Laravel 5.5. I am working on my local xampp server and trying to execute LOAD DATA INFILE query in controller function. But I am getting error PDOException (HY000)
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 29 File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\uploads\RDMST.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

Currently my csv file is located at public/uploads folder. I tried various path settings for filename like 
$fileCsv = 'uploads/RDMST.csv'; 
$fileCsv = public_path().'/uploads/RDMST.csv';

But I am getting same error and please notice the error path shows mysql\data in path. I am not getting from where it is appending this two folders in path. When I echo public path , it displays this:

D:\xampp\htdocs\tax\public

So, can you please help how to use path for load file without appending this "mysql\data" in path?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my complete controller function:

```
public function getCsv()
    {
        //echo public_path(); die;

        //$fileCsv = public_path().'/uploads/RDMST.csv'; 
        $fileCsv = 'uploads/RDMST.csv'; 

        echo $query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$fileCsv."'
            REPLACE
            INTO TABLE tblreception
            (year,
            reception_number,
            file_date,
            file_time,
            instrument_type,                                
            @created_at,
            @updated_at)
        SET created_at=NOW(),updated_at=null";
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
        //return view('reception');

    }
```

Can we not use csv file path?

Thanks

Comment: are you using `public_path()` when sourcing the .csv? We need to see some code...

Comment: Please ensure the code is added to the question rather than in the comments section.

Comment: I added my controller function as asked.

Comment: After trying many things, I sorted this by using  $fileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/RDMST.csv";  Laravel's base_path(), public_path() methods did not work and were causing issue.